# Correct way to use AutoMapper in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I'm trying to start using ViewModels - but I'm having trouble with this POST not validating - the values in the model are shown in the Watch part below the code:

**ModelStats.IsValid = false**

[image: Invalid ModelState]

My ItemViewModel is:

```
  public class ItemViewModel
  {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Price")]
    public double UnitPrice { get; set; }
    [Range(0.00, 100, ErrorMessage = "VAT must be a % between 0 and 100")]
    public decimal VAT { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
   }
```

I'm sure it will be something simple - but I've just been looking at it so long, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone please advise?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: The validation of the ViewModel is before you set the `UserName` property, so, I guess, it's null and the validation fails. Why do you need a required user name in your ViewModel anyway?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as Validation failure is concerned.

If you don't intend to supply `UserName` in the form, then remove the `[Required]` attribute from `ItemViewModel`

---

In order to Use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). You need to create a map, such as

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemViewModel>();
```

And then map

```
var itemModel = Mapper.Map<Item, ItemViewModel>(model);
```

Note: `CreateMap` has to be created only once, you should register it at Startup. Do read [How do I use AutoMapper?](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#how-do-i-use-automapper).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `ItemViewModel`, `Item` classes have same fields or not. If same fields with same Datatypes AutoMapper works fine.

```
Mapper.CreateMap< Item, ItemViewModel>();

Mapper.Map< Item, ItemViewModel>(ItemVM);
```

If Fields are not same in both the classes make sure that same with Custom Mapping.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<UserDM, UserVM>().ForMember(emp => emp.Fullname,
map => map.MapFrom(p => p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName));
```

In the above Custom Mapping `Fullname` is `UserVM` field that maps with `FirstName`, `LastName` fields from `UserDM` (here `UserDM` is Domain Model, `UserVM` is View Model).